# Background color doesn't apply to whole page Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to apply background-color property to my Vue.js application.
Since I want it to be displayed on all pages, I'm applying CSS directly to  tag in index.html:

```
<head>
<style>
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>

 <body>
   <div id="app"></div>
   <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
 </body>
```

So, as I see through the inspector, html doesn't cover the whole page[image]

How to apply background-color to the whole page?

Comment: if you could create a live demo that would help a lot

Comment: Have you tried: `body, html, #app {
  min-height: 100%;
}` ?

Comment: @laruiss still not working. It also doesn't apply background-color to html, only to the body tag

Comment: it takes the whole body - however, the body isn't full height. You need to set HTML and body to 100% height.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be working:

```
<head>
<style>
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>

 <body>
   <div id="app">
     &nbsp;
   </div>
   <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
 </body>
```

Here the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/laruiss/pen/bzwagv)

Comment: thank you very much. Solved my same issue

Answer (score 4):

CSS rule is not applied because you didn't specified the `height`, but only the `width`.

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; // add this rule
}
```